# Does the lunar orbital plane precess?

Tags: astrophysics

I read that the lunar orbit undergoes [apsidal precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsidal_precession) in which the major axis of the elliptic orbit shifts. Does the lunar orbital plane precess as well?

Comment: Yes, see the Draconic month, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_month#Draconic_month

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. This is known as nodal precession and has a period of 18.6 years. There is a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_precession) that covers both nodal and apsidial precession of the moon.

Remarkably, this effect was [known and accurately measured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_theory#Babylon) by the Babylonians in ancient times, since it is important for predicting eclipses.